# Docker: Se negó el acceso a la clave de Registro 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'

Tags: windows, docker

Acceso denegado a la hora de instalar docker

> Component CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction failed: Se negó el acceso a la clave de Registro 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'. en CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__30.MoveNext() --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción --- en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) en CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__23.MoveNext()